# Get all possible combinations without using a recursive function

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, recursion

`options.year`, `options.month` and `options.day` can hav the value `'numeric'` or `'twoDigit'`.

```
   const differentOptions = ['numeric', 'twoDigit'];
   const options = {
     year: '', month: '', day: '',
   };
```

I want to have a list with all possible combinations without using a recursion.

I know its possible with 2 loops, but I don't know how to do it.

**Expected output**

should be this 8 combinations:

```
year: 'numeric',  month: 'numeric',  year: 'numeric'

year: 'twoDigit', month: 'numeric',  year: 'numeric'

year: 'numeric',  month: 'twoDigit', year: 'numeric'

year: 'numeric',  month: 'numeric',  year: 'twoDigit'

year: 'twoDigit', month: 'twoDigit', year: 'numeric'

year: 'numeric',  month: 'twoDigit', year: 'twoDigit'

year: 'twoDigit', month: 'numeric',  year: 'twoDigit'

year: 'twoDigit', month: 'twoDigit', year: 'twoDigit'
```

***Thats what I tried***

```
   const differentOptions = [numeric, twoDigit];
   const dateAttributes = ['year', 'month', 'day']
   const options = {
     year: '', month: '', day: '',
   };

   for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     for (let j = 0; j < differentOptions.length; j++) {
       options[dateAttributes[i]] = differentOptions[j];
     }
     console.log(options);
   }
```

Comment: What have you tried ? What is the issue ?

Comment: In the scenario you're giving there are only two options. Is this something that we can expect to be hard-coded into the problem, or is there a possibility for more ?

Comment: it will always be two options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not two loop, that 2**3=8, you can write like that:

```
const answer = [];
const differentOptions = ['numeric', 'twoDigit'];
differentOptions.forEach((el) => {
    differentOptions.forEach((el1) => {
        differentOptions.forEach((el2) => {
            answer.push({
                year: el,
                month: el1,
                day: el2
            })
        })
    })
});
console.log(answer)
```

Comment: This was a great nested solution. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

Since you always have two potential values you can think of this as a counting problem with binary numbers. Each of your combinations corresponds to exactly one three digit (or more if you have more categories) binary number. For example:

`001` = `{ year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'twoDigit' }`
010`=`{year: 'numeric', month: 'twoDigit', day: 'numeric' }`

With that you can just count to `n ** 2` where n is how many keys you have:

```js
const differentOptions = ['numeric', 'twoDigit'];
const options = [ 'year', 'month','day']

for (let d = 1; d < 2 ** options.length; d++ ){
    let option_mask = Array.from(d.toString(2).padStart(options.length, '0'))
    let r = option_mask.reduce((a, c, i) => (a[options[i]] = differentOptions[c], a), {})
    console.log(r)
}
```

This is probably not the most efficient way to do this, but it's an interesting way to think about and understand the problem. And it's a general solution -- if you want to add another category, you don't need to change anything:

```js
const differentOptions = ['numeric', 'twoDigit'];

// Add minute to get 16 combinations
const options = [ 'year', 'month','day', 'minute']

for (let d = 1; d < 2 ** options.length; d++ ){
    let option_mask = Array.from(d.toString(2).padStart(options.length, '0'))
    let r = option_mask.reduce((a, c, i) => (a[options[i]] = differentOptions[c], a), {})
    console.log(r)
}
```